# Custom controlls and next and previous buttons for an embedded quicktime movie player

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, video-streaming, quicktime

I'm currently working on a website project in asp.net that hosts videos in many different languages.  They are in a series of 12 videos so I'd like to be able to embed one video player on the web page and then be able to click a next button and the next video in the list would play.  I'd also like to be able to do the save thing with a previous button as well.  Also is there a way to play and pause the video with custom controls?  I did some research on it and I found some answers in Javascript but then I went to the apple documentation and it said you can no longer use it due to security reasons.

Does anyone have any solutions for any of these?  Preferably in asp.net C# but anything will help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using the code on apple's website. In fact, I just tried it using ordinary anchor hyperlinks to play and pause a movie. Works fine. Didn't try loading a new url, but it should work too. The security restriction only applies to calling javascript from a QuickTime movie. (Which btw can still be achived using an iframe).